# Making a social network with Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, social-networking

I'm rather curious. Would it be possible to make something as complex as a basic social network (login etc) with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)?

Comment: There's a typo in the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer. Yes, but I don't know if it would be a very pleasant experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there is no way I would ever even only think about using Sinatra for that.

You can build a basic social network website with every scripting language that allows you to store and fetch data on your server.